# How can I implement swipe to delete for UITableView containing filtered data from Core Data?

Tags: swift, uitableview, core-data

I have two VC with table views, the first showing categories, and the second showing items of selected category (recipes).  I am able to get the RecipeTableVC to display filtered data using NSPredicate, but I haven't quite figured out how to delete the recipe from Core Data since the data displayed is a variable containing only the predicated data.

Here is my fetch:

```
func attemptRecipeFetch() {
    let fetchRecipeRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Recipe")
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)
    fetchRecipeRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

    let controller = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRecipeRequest, managedObjectContext: ad.managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
    fetchedRecipeController = controller

    do {
        try self.fetchedRecipeController.performFetch()
        let allRecipes = fetchedRecipeController.fetchedObjects as! [Recipe]
        recipesOfCategory = allRecipes.filter { NSPredicate(format: "category = %@", selectedCategory!).evaluateWithObject($0) }
    } catch {
        let error = error as NSError
        print("\(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
}
```

So what's populating my table is the recipesOfCategory array.

Here is my attempt to delete so far:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .Delete {
        recipesOfCategory.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        ad.managedObjectContext.delete(recipesOfCategory[indexPath.row])
    }
}
```

This crashes and I understand why, but still haven't come up with a solution.  Is there a way to implement swipe to delete where it deletes the recipe from Core Data?  Am I using the correct methodology to populate the table with filtered data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following code to '*Swipe to delete from core data*' in a table view for an App I recently did. I may work for you.

**In your "*tableView:commitEditingStyle***",

**1. set up CoreData access with ...**

> ```
> let appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
> let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext
> ```

**2. Delete the desired row + incl. from Core Data...**

> if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete {
>
> context.deleteObject(self.resultsList[indexPath.row]) // Always before
>   as CoreD
>
> ```
>         self.resultsList.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
>             do {
>                 try context.save()
>             } catch {
>                 print("Error unable to save Deletion")
>             }
>
>     } // end IF EditingStyle
>
>     self.tableView.reloadData()
> ```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't think I could remove Core Data by removing an object from my recipesOfCategory (aka your resultsList).  Worked perfectly.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

In your `tableView:commitEditingStyle:` you need to **just** delete the underlying object from Core Data, not from the table view.  The `NSFetchedResultsController` delegate methods will tell you when to remove it from the table view.

Comment: Thanks Marcus, I guess that does make sense.  I still have the same crash though.  recipesOfCategory is a variable I made up consisting of predicated data.  Is it possible to delete a Core Data entry by removing an index of recipesOfCategory?